# Dynamically appending columns of different length while looping through an empty pandas dataframe of ncols = len(columns)

Tags: python, pandas

Using for loops, I'm trying to append columns of different lengths to a pre-initialized empty dataframe. Within each iteration, I have to wrangle the data to return my desired output but the lengths of my desired outputs are all different. 
I would like to conserve every data there is (meaning that columns with shorter length will be populated with `nan` values to match the column with the longest length).

However, I realized that the shape (nrows) of the empty dataframe gets determined by the first column returned by the first iterator.

Now, I know that I can modify the shape of the empty dataframe using the nrow count from the column with max length. However, I'm curious to know if there is a pythonic way in python/pandas to modify the length of the dataframe dynamically so that the shape of the dataframe gets determined NOT from the results of the first iterator but from whichever iterator returns the column with the maximum length.

Simplified Version of the Code

```
column_list = ['File_A', 'File_B', 'File_C']

empty_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(len(column_list))

for i in range(len(column_list)):

   # "Some Code" that returns a modified dataframe of each File

   # Trying to append the `values` column from each modified dataframe into the `empty_df`

   empty_df[i] = modified_df.values
```

**Wanted Dataframe**

```
_|0     |1      |2      
0|839.0 |1163.0 |730.0
1|647.0 |826.0  |878.0
2|851.0 |725.0  |730.0  
3|nan   |1459.0 |924.0  
4|nan   |651.0  |279.0  
5|nan   |1239.0 |nan
6|nan   |373.0  |nan
```

**Resulting Dataframe**

```
_|0     |1      |2      
0|839.0 |1163.0 |730.0
1|647.0 |826.0  |878.0
2|851.0 |725.0  |730.0
```

--> Note that `Column 1` and `Column 2` have been truncated to match the length of `Column 0` (which was the first output from the first iterator)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the loop, append the `Series` to a list. Outside the loop, use `pd.concat` to concatenate the `Series`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

column_list = ['File_A', 'File_B', 'File_C']

result = []
for i in range(len(column_list)):
    # "Some Code" that returns a modified dataframe of each File
    modified_df = pd.DataFrame({'values': np.random.randint(1, 5, size=np.random.randint(10))})    
    # append the `values` column to a list    
    result.append(pd.Series(modified_df['values'], name=i))
result = pd.concat(result, axis=1)
print(result)
```

prints a result such as

```
     0  1    2
0  3.0  3  2.0
1  2.0  1  3.0
2  2.0  4  1.0
3  4.0  3  1.0
4  3.0  4  2.0
5  NaN  4  NaN
6  NaN  1  NaN
```

---

- The name of the Series will become the column label in the `result` DataFrame.
- If a DataFrame, `df`, has a column named `values`, then it must be accessed with `df['values']`, NOT `df.values`. The latter, [`df.values`, returns a NumPy array](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) of all the data in the DataFrame since `values` is a builtin DataFrame attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the solution unutbu! This worked like a charm!